# Why aren't my windows being displayed? (Ncurses)

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

I'm trying to create this program where I print two windows side by side on the stdscr. I've created the class 'menu' to declare everything about the whole screen in one place, I create a 'menu' object ('menu_principal') in main but nothing happens. I added two functions to see if my object is being created and it is.

Why aren't the windows being displayed?

Here is the class 'menu':

```
class menu{
public:
  menu(int row, int col){

    display = newwin((row-4), (col/2), 2, 0);
    getmaxyx(display, drow, dcol);

    help = newwin((row-4), (col/2), 2, (col/2));
    getmaxyx(help, hrow, hcol);

    refresh();

    box(display, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(display);

    box(help, 0,0);
    wrefresh(help);
    refresh();
  }

  int prueba1(){
    return (this->drow);
  }
  int prueba2(){
    return (this->hrow);
  }
private:
  int y, x, drow, dcol, hrow, hcol;
  WINDOW * display;
  WINDOW * help;



};
```

Here's  part of the main:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int row=0, col=0;
  initscr();
  refresh();
  cbreak();
  getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);

  menu* menu_principal = new menu(row, col);
  refresh();

  cout << row;
  cout << menu_principal->prueba1();
  cout << menu_principal->prueba2();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plain **`refresh()`** calls are overwriting the window-specific **`wrefresh(display)`** and **`wrefresh(help)`**.  If the sample were complete, someone could point to the specific line of code which is doing this.

(The **`cout`** calls don't help much: you should write that information to a file rather than to the screen).

Comment: Thanks, I moved the refresh() calls to a better place but that wasn't the problem. I realized that I wasn't instructing the program to wait before closing so I added a  "int c= getch()" statement and that solved it. Pretty noobish mistake.